# How to test if keyboard is covering UITextField in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How can I check if the keyboard is covering a first responder inside a `UIScrollView` which may or may not be a `UITableView`? Note the `UIScrollView` will not necessarily cover the entire viewController's view and may be contained in a modal view (`UIModalPresentationFormSheet`).

I'm using this modified code from [Apple's reference documentation and example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7), but `CGRectContainsPoint` will return false even when the keyboard is clearly covering the first responder. It's obvious I'm not using `convertRect:toView` correctly.

Also, Apple's code does not take into account that the view is not full-screen, so setting the scrollView's contentInset to the full height of the keyboard isn't a great solution -- it should only be inset for the portion of the keyboard covering the firstResponder.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification

{
    // self.scrollView can be a tableView or not. need to handle both
    UIView *firstResponderView = [self.scrollView findFirstResponder];
    if (!firstResponderView)
        return;

    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGRect rect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    // convertRect:toView? convertRect:fromView? Always confusing
    CGRect kbRect = [self.scrollView convertRect:rect toView:nil];
    CGRect viewRect = [self.scrollView convertRect:firstResponderView.bounds toView:nil];

    // doesn't work. convertRect misuse is certainly to blame 
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(kbRect, firstResponderView.frame.origin))
        return;

    // Only inset to the portion which the keyboard covers?
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbRect.size.height, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Comment: As a side note: This is also not doing what you probably want to do: `[self.scrollView convertRect:firstResponderView.bounds toView:nil]`. `firstResponderView.bounds` is not in scroll view coordinates, but in the local coordinate system of `firstResponderView`. You probably want to use the frame here (which is in the superview's CS.

Answer (score 2):

Without further testing or having a deep look at the logic, this line seems odd:

```
CGRect kbRect = [self.scrollView convertRect:rect toView:nil];
```

The keyboard rect (that is included in the notification) is in *window* coordinates and you probably want to convert it into the scroll view coordinate system. `[viewA convertRect:rect toView:viewB]` converts rect from viewA's coordinate system to viewB's coordinate system, so you are actually doing the opposite of what you should be doing (as you suspected).

What I'm usually doing is this:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGRect kbRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    kbRect = [self.view.window convertRect:kbRect toView:self.view];    // convert to local coordinate system, otherwise it is in window coordinates and does not consider interface orientation
    _keyboardSize = kbRect.size;    // store for later use

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, MAX(0.0f, CGRectGetMaxY(_tableView.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(kbRect)), 0.0f);    // NB: _tableView is a direct subview of self.view, thus _tableView.frame and kbRect are in the same coordinate system
        _tableView.contentInset = insets;
        _tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;
        [self scrollToActiveTextField];    // here I adapt the content offset to ensure that the active text field is fully visible
    }];
}
```

Comment: Just noticed that my approach actually addresses exactly your concern ("Note the UIScrollView will not necessarily cover the entire viewController's view and may be contained in a modal view"), because I'm not just blindly using the keyboard's height to adapt the content insets, but actually consider the scrollview's frame and only adapt by the delta that is actually covered by the keyboard.

Comment: I should have noted that `self.view` isn't available to use. Keyboard dodging is being handled by a scrollview manager class which is passed the scrollView to manage on init and then held in a weak reference. Any issues with replacing `self.view` with `self.scrollView`?

Comment: Well, the scroll view coordinate system is actually affected by scrolling, so probably not a good idea.. ;) What about using `self.scrollView.superview`?

Comment: Yep, that would work as long as it's not expected to be the root view in the hierarchy.

Comment: I would also note that the animation duration should be pulled from the info dictionary rather than hard coded.